# For loop - how to reference objects in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, state

Being a beginner in React.js, I have a for-loop below that cycles through all form elements in the state and outputs JSX components accordingly to be rendered. At the moment I only have 2 elements in my form. If I access them directly  via `this.state.form.username.placeHolder`, I get access to the value. However, when I use the for-loop and use for each 'component', `component.placeHolder` is `undefined`.

Would be very grateful if someone could let me know what I am doing wrong.

Tried putting console logs everywhere. It appears it just doesn't like the syntax of `component.placeHolder`.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import classes from './SignInUpForm.module.css';
import Input from './Input/Input';
import Icon from '../../Assets/Icons/icon1.svg';

class SignInUpForm extends Component{

    state={
        form:{
            username:
            {placeHolder: "Username",
            type: "text",
            icon: {Icon},
            validation:{
                required: true,
            },
            valid: false},

            password:
            {placeHolder: "Password",
            type: "text",
            icon: {Icon},
            validation:{
                required: true,
            },
            valid: false}
        }
    }



render(){

    const formArray = [];

    for (let component in this.state.form){
        console.log(this.state.form);
        console.log(component);
        console.log(component.placeholder);
        console.log(component.icon);
        formArray.push(

            <Input key = {component} name = {component} placeholder={component.placeHolder} icon ={component.icon}/>

            );


    }



    return(
            <React.Fragment>
            <div className={classes.SignInUpForm}>
            {formArray}
            </div>

            </React.Fragment>
    );
}

}
export default SignInUpForm;


placeholder={component.placeHolder} icon ={component.icon} are undefined. They should not be.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`state.form` in an object and not an array. So, when you iterate over an object using `for-in`, you get the key. Meaning "username" and "password" in your `component` variable.

To achieve what you want, you can do `this.state.form[component]`.

```js
let state = {
  form: {
    username: {
      placeHolder: "Username",
      type: "text",
      icon: "foo",
      validation: {
        required: true,
      },
      valid: false
    },

    password: {
      placeHolder: "Password",
      type: "text",
      icon: "foo",
      validation: {
        required: true,
      },
      valid: false
    }
  }
};


for (let component in state.form) {
  console.log(state.form[component].placeHolder);
  console.log(state.form[component].icon);
}
```

Also, there's a typing mistake in your code. In the state you have `placeHolder` (camelCase) but you are accessing it as `placeholder` (small case)

Answer (score 0):

As per [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> The for...in statement iterates over all enumerable **properties** of an
>   object.

That means `component` variable will have the properties of the object not the values. To access the values, you need to use `this.state.form[component].placeholder`.

```
for (let component in this.state.form){
  console.log('component', component);
  console.log('values', this.state.form[component].placeholder);
}
```

To avoid the confusion, better to use `key` instead of component.

Check this Example:

```js
let obj = { a:1, b: 2 };

for(let key in obj) {
  console.log('key value => ', key, obj[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead, it will make your code cleaner as well:

```
const formFieldNames = Object.keys(this.state.form);

const formArray = formFieldNames.map(fieldName => {
   const field = formFieldNames[fieldName];
   return <Input key={fieldName} placeholder={field.placeholder} icon={field.icon}/>
});
```

Also I would model your form fields as an array instead.

And you maybe want to use: https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/, it will make your life way easier.